# How to modify a String in EditText by pressing Buttons in Android

Tags: android

I am making a Simple Calculator, I have added 0-9 Buttons ans well as Operations such as +, -, /, * etc...

I added a Button and set its onClick event as android:onClick="Press_1"

and its Corresponding OnClick Method is

```
    public void Press_1(View view)
    {
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);
    editText.setText("1");
    }
```

Now i want to create similarly for Button_2,Button_3 and so on... !
On pressing the buttons i want the Corresponding digits to get displayed on the editText.
Everything works fine, but i am not able to Append/Modify the EditText. Example: I want to write the number "6754",
so i need to press '6' '7' '5' and '4' respectively , but after i press '7', the '6' disappears, and finally i get only '4' in the EditText. Please help me i am new to this ???
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of editText.setText(), you want to use editText.append()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 1):

Use a field variable to store your current text:

```
private String currentText = "";
```

Then on a button press:

```
//On press 1
currentText = currentText + "1";
editText.setText(currentText);
```

This way you have the value to calculate with always quick at hand.